# Fatal Error: MySQL Insert from VB.net of Date datatype

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, date, types

I am trying to Insert data into a MySQL database. I have everything working perfectly except for one column in my database which is a Date datatype. I have created a simple VB project to demonstrate my code.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

         Using SQLConnection = New MySqlConnection("Server=www.server.com.au;Database=dbtest;Uid=dbtest;Pwd=dbtest;")
            Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand()

            sqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test (`test`) values (@test)"
            sqlCommand.Connection = SQLConnection

            Dim DateOrdered As New MySqlParameter("@test", MySqlDbType.Date, 0)
            DateOrdered.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                Try
                    sqlCommand.Prepare()
                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("Query: " & ex.Message)
                End Try
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox("SQLConnection: " & ex.Message.ToString)
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

I receive an error message from line `MessageBox.Show("Query: " & ex.Message)`. The message reads "Query: Fatal error encountered during command execution". I know the error is in my syntax but I cannot work out the correct format to make it work.

I have this working in a much larger project using varchar, int and Decimal datatypes but cannot work out the Date type.

I created a new project. Put a DateTimePicker and a button on the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if the db column is `Date` or `Datetime` do not pass it a string.  use `DateOrdered.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried this and it does not work. I have also tried changing the Datatype from Date to DateTime with no luck.

Comment: I continued working on this and got it working. I felt all along the error was to do with the formatting of the Date.

This worked....
`DateOrdered.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

I will investigate the format options for the DateTimePicker for my own info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued working on this and got it working.

I felt all along the error was to do with the formatting of the Date. 
This worked.... 
`DateOrdered.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

I will investigate the format options for the DateTimePicker for my own info.

More Info:
Alternatively, if I set the CustomFormat property to yyyy-MM-dd and use the `DateTimePicker1.Text' value, I do not need to perform any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code when setting up your SqlCommand to run.

```
      Dim DateOrdered As New MySqlParameter("@test", MySqlDbType.Date, 0)
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(DateOrdered)
      sqlCommand.Prepare()
```

Then use this code each time you run it.

```
      sqlCommand.Parameters(0).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
      sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

By doing this you're **passing the value of your picker field directly**, rather than forcing it to be a text string.  And, you're **associating your parameter with your SqlCommand**, a necessary part of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried this and it does not work. I have also tried changing the Datatype from Date to DateTime with no luck.

Comment: I continued working on this and got it working. I felt all along the error was to do with the formatting of the Date. This worked.... DateOrdered.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) I will investigate the format options for the DateTimePicker for my own info.